# to_csv append mode is not appending to next new line

Tags: python, csv, append, export-to-csv

I have a csv called `test.csv` that looks like:

```
accuracy    threshold   trainingLabels
abc         0.506       15000
eew         18.12       15000
```

And then a dataframe called `summaryDF` that looks like:

```
accuracy    threshold   trainingLabels
def         0.116       342
dja         0.121       1271
```

I am doing:

```
try:
        if os.stat('test.csv').st_size > 0:
                summaryDF.to_csv(path_or_buf=f, encoding='utf-8', mode='a', header=False)
                f.close()
        else:
            print "empty file"
            with open('test.csv', 'w+') as f:
                summaryDF.to_csv(path_or_buf=f, encoding='utf-8')
                f.close()
    except OSError:
        print "No file"
        with open('test.csv', 'w+') as f:
            summaryDF.to_csv(path_or_buf=f, encoding='utf-8')
            f.close()
```

Because I want my file to be:

```
accuracy    threshold   trainingLabels
abc         0.506       15000
eew         18.12       15000
def         0.116       342
dja         0.121       1271
```

Instead, it is:

```
accuracy    threshold   trainingLabels
abc         0.506       15000
eew         18.12       15000def            0.116       342   
dja         0.121       1271
```

How can I solve this? I am guessing using a CSV writer instead of `to_csv` but clearly the append mode is not skipping the last line of the existing file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using the pandas package? You do not mention that anywhere.

Pandas does not automatically append a new line, and I am not sure how to force it. But you can just do:

```
f.write('\n')
summaryDF.to_csv(path_or_buf=f, mode='a', ...)
```

---

An unrelated bug in your code:

You seem to have a global file object called `f`.

When you do this:

```
with open('test.csv', 'w+') as f:
    ...
    f.close()
```

The file that you are closing there is the file that you just opened in the `with` block. You are not closing the global file `f` because the variable was overshadowed by the `f` in that scope.

Is this what you want? Either way, it makes no sense. The reason why we use the `with` scope is to avoid having to close the file explicitly.

You either use:

```
f = open('filename')
...
f.close()
```

OR

```
with open('filename') as f:
    ...
```

You do not close a file opened within a `with` block. Using a `with` block has the additional advantage that the file gets closed even if an exception is raised and the following code is not executed.